# Getting common key value pairs from nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

Im trying to create a nested dictionary by combining two dictionaries on common key value pairs

The dictionaries are as follows:

```
dict1 = {'employee': {1: {'empId': 1, 'salary': 1000}, 2: {'empId': 2, 'salary': 2000}}}
dict2 = {'time': {1: {'empId': 1, 'avgtime': 55}, 2: {'empId': 1, 'avgtime': 25}, 3: {'empId': 2, 'avgtime': 25}}}
```

I want to combine the two to create one dictionary with time being a nested dictionary inside employee, as shown below.....

```
dict3 = {'employee': {1: {'empId': 1, 'salary': 1000, 'avgtime': {1: 55, 2: 25}}}, 2: {'empId': 2, 'salary': 2000, 'avgtime': {1: 25}}}
```

I have tried a couple of things and can get the entire dict2 to append to the end of dict1 but cant quite figure out how to add a nested dict each time there is a key/value match

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    for thing1, thing2 in list(zip(d1['employee'].values(), d2['time'].values())):
        d1['time'] = {}
        for k in thing1.items():
            if k in thing2.items():
                d1['time'].update(thing2)
        return d1
a = merge(dict1,dict2)
print(a)
```

The above output gives the following outcome but its the closest I've gotten

```
{'employee': {1: {'empId': 1, 'salary': 1000}, 2: {'empId': 2, 'salary': 2000}}, 'time': {'empId': 1, 'avgtime': 55}}
```

So my question is how would I combine these two dicts into one on the common key value pairs as shown in dict3

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Your desired output is not clear.  First, your data input is far from minimal, so the critical question gets lost in the extra fields.  Second, your desired output magically generates a "day 2" dict, when there is no corresponding data in the input -- the method of merging is quite unclear.

Comment: Okay had another crack at it, hope its clearer now

Comment: I'll wait until you've finished the MRE.

Comment: Okay, i've had another attempt at making it clearer, I hope its better now, if not could you please be more specific as to what you would like to see more/less off? Im just trying to learn and would appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must think about this as a database, where dict1 is the master.  You can't use "zip", because the records don't line up one for one.  You have to search the dict2 records to find the matching employee IDs.  Also note that you don't really have to return "d1"; your code is modifying dict1 in place.  This does what you ask:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    for k1,v1 in d1['employee'].items():
        v1['avgtime'] = {}
        for k2,v2 in d2['time'].items():
            if v2['empId'] == v1['empId']:
                v1['avgtime'][k2] = v2['avgtime']
merge(dict1,dict2)
print(dict1)
```

Comment: Oh okay yes completely makes sense! Thanks a lot, this really helps!